# How to collapse a column of logicals into TRUE FALSE TRUE... and create a new column with the original number of consecutive values?

Tags: r, list, dictionary, lapply

I would like to create new data frames within a list, where TRUE and FALSE logicals alternate and in a new column the number about how often they showed up consecutively in the original dataframes within lists.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(94756)
mat1 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5) 
mat1 <- as_tibble(mat1)

mat2 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat2 <- as_tibble(mat2)

mat3 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11), 50,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat3 <- as_tibble(mat3)

data <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)

data1 <- purrr::map(data, ~tibble::add_column(., V1_logical = between(.$V2, 20, 60), .after = 'V1'))
r_pre <- lapply(data1, "[", 2)
```

That in the end I get an example like this:

```
$logical = TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE ...
$length = 2, 1, 3 (=marker), 2, 1, 3, 7...
```

Comment: It feels like the base `rle` function might be useful here, but I'm not sure I understand how the elements of the list are combining.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```r
bind_rows(r_pre, .id = "i") %>% group_by(i) %>% count(V1_logical)
```

?

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   i [3]
  i     V1_logical     n
  <chr> <lgl>      <int>
1 1     FALSE          3
2 1     TRUE           7
3 2     FALSE          5
4 2     TRUE           5
5 3     FALSE          2
6 3     TRUE           8
```

You could also do this with `map` (and it might be a hair more efficient), but this seems to work ...

If you want the number of *runs* of TRUE/FALSE, e.g. that a vector `{TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}` should result in a component (2, 2, 1) (numbers in consecutive runs of T/F), and assuming you want all of the results concatenated into a single tibble, try something like

```
rfun <- function(x) with(rle(x[[1]]), tibble(lengths, values))
purrr::map_dfr(r_pre, rfun)
```

```r
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   lengths values
     <int> <lgl> 
 1       1 TRUE  
 2       1 FALSE 
 3       2 TRUE  
 4       1 FALSE 
...
```

If you want it as a list of three tibbles, just use `purrr::map` instead of `map_dfr`:

```r
purrr::map(r_pre, rfun)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  lengths values
    <int> <lgl> 
1       1 TRUE  
2       1 FALSE 
3       2 TRUE  
4       1 FALSE 
5       4 TRUE  
6       1 FALSE 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  lengths values
    <int> <lgl> 
1       2 TRUE  
2       1 FALSE 
3       1 TRUE  
4       2 FALSE 
5       1 TRUE  
6       2 FALSE 
7       1 TRUE  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  lengths values
    <int> <lgl> 
1       2 FALSE 
2       8 TRUE
```

Comment: Your last comment is exactly what I would like to have :) I mean the data within the brackets (2,2,1) for your data example

Comment: and how would the information from the individual elements in the list be combined?  Would the result be a list of 2-column tibbles, or a single concatenated 2-element tibble, or ... ?

Comment: I am just a beginner. Actually I don't know... This is part of a bigger question. Have a look at the attached link, maybe things become clear then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352120/how-to-add-a-new-column-in-dataframes-within-a-list-and-count-the-logical-number. I already have a code without a list, but for working with big data it would be great to work with lists instead of single documents.

Comment: It still includes all data in one "length" and one "values". Would be great to bring it for all single dataframes, so three times "length" and "values" here in this example.